# Convergence of an adelic integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, adeles, poisson-summation-formula

Let $F$ be a Schwarz-Bruhat function on $\mathbb A = \mathbb A_{\mathbb Q}$, i.e. a finite sum of products of the form $\prod\limits_{p \leq \infty} f_p$, where $f_{\infty}$ is a Schwarz function on $\mathbb R$, and $f_p$ for $p < \infty$ is a locally constant and compactly supported function on $\mathbb Q_p$.

I'm trying to understand the convergence of the sum of integrals (over $\mathbb A^{\ast}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}$)

$$\int\limits_{ \substack{a \in \mathbb A^{\ast}/\mathbb Q^{\ast} \\ |a| \geq 1}} \sum\limits_{0 \neq \eta \in \mathbb Q} F(a \eta)|a| d^{\ast} a + \int\limits_{|a| \leq 1} \sum\limits_{0 \neq \eta}\hat{F}(a^{-1} \eta)d^{\ast}a $$

$$+ \hat{F}(0) \int\limits_{|a| \leq 1}(1-\chi_c(|a|^{-1}))d^{\ast}a - F(0)\int\limits_{|a| \leq 1}|a| d^{\ast}a.$$

Here $c > 1$ is a real number, $\chi_c$ is the characteristic function of $[c,\infty)$, and $\hat{F}(a) = \int\limits_{\mathbb A} F(y) \psi(ay)dy$ is the Fourier transform, where $\psi$ is a nontrivial character of $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$.  It is also a Schwarz-Bruhat function.

These appear in the geometric side of Arthur's modified trace formula for $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ (Corvallis I, *Forms of GL(2) from the analytic point of view*, page 236), in the proof of the convergence of the truncated kernels.

The last two integrals I understand.  For example, the second to last term is

$$\hat{F}(0) \int\limits_{\mathbb A^{\ast 1}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}} \int_1^c \frac{dt}{t} d^{\ast}a = \hat{F}(0) \textrm{vol}(\mathbb A^{\ast 1}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}) \log(c).$$

How can one establish the convergence  of the first two integrals?  I would appreciate any hint in this direction.

Comment: $\hat{F}$ is the Fourier transform of $\sum_{\eta\in \Bbb{Q}^*} F(\eta a)$.. I don't understand what is $\int\limits_{|a| \leq 1} \sum\limits_{0 \neq \eta}\hat{F}(a^{-1} \eta)d^{\ast}a$. Can you please make a bit more efforts in presenting the thing?

Comment: All four integrals are over subsets of $\mathbb A^{\ast}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}$.  I labeled the first integral explicitly, so I thought that would be clear from the context.

Comment: I defined the Fourier transform in the body of the question.  The Fourier transform is of functions on $\mathbb A$, not on $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$ (so again $\hat{F}$ is a function from $\mathbb A$ to $\mathbb C$, not a function from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb C$).  Clear?

Comment: Did you try $\int\limits_{ \substack{a \in \mathbb A^{\ast}/\mathbb Q^{\ast} \\ |a| \geq 1}} \sum\limits_{0 \neq \eta \in \mathbb Q} F(a \eta)|a| d^{\ast} a=
\int\limits_{a\in \mathbb A^{\ast},|a|\ge 1} F(a)|a| d^{\ast} a
=\int\limits_{a\in \mathbb A,|a|\ge 1} F(a) d^+ a
$. It converges because the $f_p$ are supported on $\Bbb{Z}_p$ for all but finitely many $p$, so $\prod_p \int_{\Bbb{Q}_p} f_p(x)dx=C<\infty$, for $G=f_\infty\prod_p f_p $ you get $\int\limits_{a\in \mathbb A,|a|\ge 1} |G(a)| d a\le \int_\Bbb{R} C |f_\infty(x)|dx$.

Comment: That said I have zero idea what your expression is supposed to represent.

Comment: Thank you very much, that answers my question.  The sum of the four integrals is the nilpotent regular contribution of the integral over the diagonal for the truncated kernel for $\operatorname{GL}_2$, which I want to show converges.